# laravel model events change data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if an object is undefined in the template it always says

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'small' of undefined"
```

Javascript:

```
tmpl += '<td rowspan="3">' + (d.images[0].small !== undefined) ? 
'<img alt="" src="' + d.images[0].small +  '">' :  '' + '</td>';
```

Also tried underscore and I get the same error

```
tmpl += '<td rowspan="3">' + (!_.isUndefined(d.images[0].small)) ? 
'<img alt="" src="' + d.images[0].small +  '">' :  '' + '</td>';
```

This is a template in datatables

Comment: Not all rows will have an image so there would be no object

Comment: Check for the length of the array so d.images[0] is never undefined d.images.length > 0 ?